# Replacing cell array element with cell subarray

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave, dynamic-arrays, cells

I have to implement a Huffman encoder in MATLAB/Octave (unfortunately), so I am using a cell array for maximum flexibility. I want to append symbol indices as they are merged to the earlier indices so I can track what symbols are merged as the processing goes up the tree.

Here's an example:

```
Index  Prob.           Index  Prob.         Index  Prob.
1      0.5             1      0.5           1      0.5
2      0.2             3,4    0.3 ---> 0.4  2,3,4  0.4
3      0.2  ---> 0.3   2      0.1 ---/
4      0.1  ---/
```

As you can see, symbols 3 and 4 get merged, and then the indices are merged and both lists are resorted in descending order of probability.

So I declared a cell array:

```
  % cell index
  myinds = num2cell(1:numel(probs));

  D = 2; % binary
```

Unfortunately, when I try to merge the two, I get a size mismatch error;

```
% 3. add subtrees
    myinds(end-(D-1)) = [myinds(end-(D-1)) mergedinds(2:end)];
    % remove merged leaves
    myinds((end-D):end) = []
```

The output of either side seems conceptually to be what I want, though:

```
octave> [myinds(end-(D-1)) mergedinds(2:end)]
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =  3
  [1,2] =  4
}

octave> myinds(end-(D-1))
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =  6
}
```

I would like to store the `Index` column above as the algorithm steps through the illustrated process. I can just grow a matrix each time but that's slow and inefficient. As I understand it a cell array will do what I want, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear to me.

Comment: which part is unclear?

Comment: Could you use a toy example and tell us what you want? Give an input and the expected output.

Comment: I can't exactly give the expected output because I don't know how to make it work with cells, but the above illustration is an accurate description of what I am trying to build.